# The age of three ladies

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Three ladies A, B and C have a discussion, where each lady says the truth twice and lies once.

1. A: B is two years older than me
2. B: C is 38 years old
3. C: A is older than me
4. B: The age difference between C and me is three years
5. C: A is 36 years old
6. A: I'm 35 years old
7. B: At least one of A or C is younger then me
8. A: I'm one year older than C
9. C: A is three years younger than B

What is the age of each of the three ladies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A says:

- $B = A + 2$
- $A = 35$
- $A = C + 1$

B says:

- $C = 38$
- $|B - C| = 3$
- $A < B$ or $C < B$

C says:

- $A > C$
- $A = 36$
- $B = A + 3$

Notice that

> A and C have two pairs of conficting statements. This means that they are both correct on one and wrong on the other. And their remaining statements are both true.
>
>  Thus $A = C + 1$ and $A > C$ are true. Also, $A = 35$ or $36$.

This means that

> $C = 34$ or $35$, making the statement $C = 38$ false.
>
>  Therefore the other two statements of B are true.

Now we see that

> $|B - C| = 3$ means that $B, C$ have different parity.
>
>  But we also know $A = C + 1$, hence $A, B$ have the same parity.

This forces

> $B = A + 3$ to be false, thus $A = 36$, $C = 35$ and $B = A + 2 = 38$.

Comment: just beat me to it! well done

Comment: One problem with your logic - "both correct on one and wrong on the other" is not true. The two conflicting statements could have both been lies.

Comment: @RobWatts In each pair of conflicting statements, at least one is false. There are two pairs of conflicting statements between A and C, thus at least two of these statements are false. But A and C have only two false statements in total, one for each. Therefore there is no other false statement - in particular, in each conflicting pair, exactly one statement is false.

Comment: I see what I missed. "A and C have two conficting statements" would be better as "A and C have two pairs of conflicting statements."

Comment: @RobWatts Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing out. I updated the answer to make this clear.